# MySQL Query Left Join Problem To Get Data

Tags: mysql

I want show data liker here :

```
id_produk | jumlah_liker | id_user
1         |            5 | 1
2         |            0 | 1
```

Review Table produk

```
pr_id | nama
1     | Milk
2     | Choco
```

Review Table liker

```
id_produk | id_user
1         | 1 
1         | 1 
1         | 1 
1         | 1 
1         | 1
```

But i got sql record

```
id_produk | jumlah_liker | id_user
1         | 1            | 1 //the problem here
2         | 0            | 1

SELECT liker.id_produk, COUNT(liker.id_produk) AS jumlah_like, liker.id_user 
    FROM produk 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN liker ON liker.id_produk = produk.pr_id AND liker.id_user = 1
    GROUP BY produk.pr_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` both the `id_produk` and `id_user` columns.  Also, you should be selecting and aggregating on the id from the `produk` table.  The whole point of doing a left join from `produk` is to ensure that each product will always appear in the output.

```
SELECT
    p.pr_id,         -- NOT liker.id_produk
    COUNT(l.id_produk) AS jumlah_like,
    l.id_user 
FROM produk p
LEFT JOIN liker l
    ON l.id_produk = p.pr_id AND l.id_user = 1
GROUP BY
    p.pr_id,
    l.id_user;
```

### Demo

Comment: Same record i got sir